# How request Live Location from user telegram bot Api?

Tags: python, api, location, bots, telegram

Using the Bot Api and java, I am writing a bot to track the user's location. But the location can only be obtained statically, via requestLocation. How do I request a Live location from a user?

```
 private ReplyKeyboardMarkup getInitKeyboard(String text) {

        ReplyKeyboardMarkup replyKeyboardMarkup = new ReplyKeyboardMarkup();
        replyKeyboardMarkup.setSelective(true);
        replyKeyboardMarkup.setResizeKeyboard(true);
        List<KeyboardRow> keyboard = new ArrayList<>();
        KeyboardRow keyboardRow = new KeyboardRow();
        KeyboardButton keyboardButton = new KeyboardButton(text);

        keyboardButton.setRequestLocation(true);
        keyboardRow.add(keyboardButton);
        keyboard.add(keyboardRow);
        replyKeyboardMarkup.setKeyboard(keyboard);

        return replyKeyboardMarkup;
    }
```

used librery telegram.telegrambots-meta:5.4.0.1
Help me please